# Code/Program memory and caching

Tags: multithreading, memory, concurrency, parallel-processing, microprocessors

I know that any data could be cached from main memory to cache memory that provides faster access from the CPU than does main memory.

I know as well that each thread has it's own stack memory.

**So the question is, could the program/code memory be cached as well? or is the caching exclusive to data blocks, not instructions block?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the machine instructions of the program can be cached as well.  In fact, some processors have separate caches for instructions and data, while in other processors they share a single cache.